# Access SQL statement doesn't always work when passing parameters with a VBA function

Tags: sql, vba, function, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am using MS Access 2013 and I have a table where one of the fields is a dropdown that looks up values from another table. I am passing IDs to a SQL statement using a vba function and SQL IN() clause.  It works with one value, when more than one value is passed it returns no records or a data type mismatch.

```vb
DIM varIDs AS String
```

VBA Function

```
getIDs(varIDs)
```

SQL Statement

```sql
SELECT ID, Name FROM Table 
WHERE Table.ID IN (getIDs())
```

When varIDs = "26" it works
When varIDs = "26, 27" it doesn't return anything or returns a data type mismatch

Been searching for an answers for 2 days and can't figure why its not working with multiple IDs being passed.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hello jarlh,  I'm not using an array, the IDs being returned is a string

Comment: You don't want to use a comma-separated string for IDs. You want to join on a temp table that contains the IDs you want. Does Access do temp tables?

Comment: In the SQL statement if I manually enter the IDs instead of the function it works fine

Comment: It does work.  You just have no ideas like look like `"26,27"` (comma included.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work like this. The SQL is **not** expanded to `WHERE Table.ID IN (26, 27)` as you might expect.

Change your VBA function to test for valid IDs instead

```vb
Public Function IsValidId(ByVal id As Long) As Boolean
    IsValidId = id = 26 Or id = 27 'Replace by your implementation
End Function
```

Then change your SQL to

```sql
SELECT ID, Name FROM Table 
WHERE IsValidId(Table.ID)
```

---

Another approach, if you can change the query dynamically (e.g. for a ComboBox),  is to create it like this

```vb
Dim sql as String
sql = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Table WHERE Table.ID IN (" & getIDs() & ")"
cbo.RowSource = sql
```

Comment: Thank you all for taking the time to respond...@Olivier, I was able to get it to work using your alternate approach, I build the entire sql statement with the appropriate IDs and then I update the DAO, CurrentDB.TableDefs("Table").Fields("Field").Properties("RowSource") = sql Hoorah, worked like a charm!